# Yii2 ActiveQuery join relation issue

Tags: php, yii2, left-join

ActiveQuery doesn't select **map.src_fin_position_id** column

```
$query = FinancePossibleFinPositions::find()
            ->select (['dst.row_num', 'dst.src_value', 'map.src_fin_position_id'])
            ->from('finance.possible_fin_positions dst')
            ->leftJoin('finance.fin_pos_mapping map','map.map_fin_position_id = dst.possible_fin_positions_id')
            ->leftJoin('finance.possible_fin_positions src','src.possible_fin_positions_id = map.src_fin_position_id AND src.possible_fin_docs_id = :possible_fin_docs_id',[":possible_fin_docs_id"=> 95])
            ->where('dst.possible_fin_docs_id=:possible_fin_docs_id', [":possible_fin_docs_id"=> 88])
            ->orderBy('dst.row_num')
            ->all();
```

gives

```
array(2) {
   ["row_num"]=>
    string(4) "1000"
    ["src_value"]=>
    string(18) "My value"
}
```

although

```
$query = (new \yii\db\Query())
                ->select(["dst.row_num", "dst.src_value", "map.src_fin_position_id"])
                ->from('finance.possible_fin_positions dst')
                ->join('LEFT JOIN','finance.fin_pos_mapping map','map.map_fin_position_id = dst.possible_fin_positions_id')
                ->join('LEFT JOIN','finance.possible_fin_positions src','src.possible_fin_positions_id = map.src_fin_position_id AND src.possible_fin_docs_id = :possible_fin_docs_id',[":possible_fin_docs_id"=> $fin_doc])
                ->where('dst.possible_fin_docs_id=:possible_fin_docs_id', [":possible_fin_docs_id"=> $main_fin_doc])
                ->orderBy('dst.row_num')->all();
```

gives the result I need to get with ActiveQuery

```
array(3) {
    ["row_num"]=>
    string(4) "1000"
    ["src_value"]=>
    string(18) "My value"
    ["src_fin_position_id"]=>
    int(3426)
  }
```

I would use `\yii\db\Query()` but when I fill tabular form with this array the **$_POST** is empty.
Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

**UPDATE**

Simpler example

form.php

```
<div class="col-md-6">
        <?php  
            $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id'=>'post-multiple','action' => ['submit-posts']]);
            echo TabularForm::widget([
            'form' => $form,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'serialColumn' => false,
            'actionColumn' => false,
            'checkboxColumn' => false,
            'attributes' => [
                'post_id' => ['type' => TabularForm::INPUT_STATIC, 'columnOptions'=>['hAlign'=>GridView::ALIGN_CENTER]],
                'post_title' => ['type' => TabularForm::INPUT_STATIC],
                'post_description' => ['type' => TabularForm::INPUT_TEXT, 'options' => ['class' => 'droppable']],
            ],
            'gridSettings' => [
                'floatHeader' => true,
                'panel' => [
                    'heading' => '<h3 class="panel-title"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></i> Manage Books</h3>',
                    'type' => GridView::TYPE_PRIMARY,
                    'after'=> 
                        Html::a(
                            '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add New', 
                            '#', 
                            ['class'=>'btn btn-success']
                        ) . '&nbsp;' . 
                        Html::a(
                            '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Delete', 
                            '#', 
                            ['class'=>'btn btn-danger']
                        ) . '&nbsp;' .
                        Html::submitButton(
                            '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></i> Save', 
                            ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']
                        )
                ]
            ]     
        ]); 
        ActiveForm::end(); ?>
    </div>
```

Controllers

```
        public function actionTabular()
        {
    //      $query = (new \yii\db\Query())
    //      ->select("post_id, post_title, post_description")
    //      ->from('posts');

            $query = Posts::find()->indexBy('post_id');

            $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
                    'query' => $query,
                    'pagination' => false,
            ]);

            return $this->render('tabular', [
                'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
            ]);
        }
    public function actionSubmitPosts() 
    {
        var_dump(Yii::$app->request->post());exit;
}


$query = Posts::find()->indexBy('post_id');

<input type="text" id="posts-40-post_description" class="droppable form-control ui-droppable" name="Posts[40][post_description]" value="tre">
```

$_POST is not empty

```
$query = (new \yii\db\Query())
->select("post_id, post_title, post_description")
->from('posts');

<input type="text" id="-28-post_description" class="droppable ui-droppable" name="[28][post_description]" value="tre">
```

$_POST is empty

Both queries fill the form correctly
The difference is inputs names. But I don't need to validate this form and it is strange why

[28][post_description] doesn't go into $_POST.

Comment: update your question and show the code where you "fill tabular form with this array"

Answer (score 0):

From [Yii 2 Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#relational-data):

> **Note**: If you call select() while eagerly loading relations, you have to make sure the columns referenced in the relation declarations are being selected. Otherwise, the related models may not be loaded properly. For example,

```
$orders = Order::find()->select(['id', 'amount'])->with('customer')->all();
// $orders[0]->customer is always null.
// To fix the problem, you should do the following:
$orders = Order::find()
    ->select(['id', 'amount', 'customer_id'])
    ->with('customer')->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. 
For **yii\db\Query**

I should have used

```
<?= Html::beginForm(['save-posts','method'=>'post']); ?>
```